# Combining columns in R table function

Tags: r, dataframe

I am currently learning R and I encountered problems with tabulating data.

I have integer scores in a data frame, `model`, that range from 1 to 10 (inclusive). When I use the table function, i.e.

```
table(model$score)
```

I get the following result:

```
  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
  5  6  8  7  2  3  6  4  5  0
```

However, I want to tabulate the data in the following format:

```
  1-2  3-4  5-6  7-8  9-10
   11   15    5   10     5
```

Is it possible to achieve this with the table function or do I have to seek the help of another function/package? How do I do it then? Is there a similar way for the `prop.table` function?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not simply do this?

```
x <- table(model$score)
x <- x[c(1,3,5,7,9)] + x[c(2,4,6,8,10)]
names(x) <- c("1-2","3-4","5-6","7-8","9-10")
```

It does not introduce extra complexity at all.

`table` will of course give you a vector of length-10, because you have 10 unique levels.

Well, if you insist calling `table()` to get the result you want, you need to use `cut()` to classify your data into bins:

```
set.seed(0); a <- sample(1:10, 200, replace = TRUE)
table(cut(a, breaks = c(0,2,4,6,8,10)))

 (0,2]  (2,4]  (4,6]  (6,8] (8,10] 
    29     45     43     47     36
```

Change the label? Use `labels` (inside `cut()`):

```
table(cut(a, breaks = c(0,2,4,6,8,10), labels = c("1-2","3-4","5-6","7-8","9-10")))

 1-2  3-4  5-6  7-8 9-10 
  29   45   43   47   36
```

But you must make sure `a` is numerical. You will get error if:

```
a <- factor(a)
table(cut(a, breaks = c(0,2,4,6,8,10)))

Error in cut.default(a, breaks = c(0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10)) : 
  'x' must be numeric
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. I think I'll just stick to your first method of doing things as it is simple but good enough for me at this point in time. I was also ignorant of the cut function.

Answer (score 4):

You could also use `zoo` package,

```
library(zoo)
rollapply(table(model$score), 2, by = 2, sum)
```

Using @Zheyuan Li's example, (updated as per @G.Grothendieck's comment)

```
tt <- rollapply(table(a), 2, by = 2, sum)
names(tt) <- rollapply(names(table(a)), 2, by = 2, paste, collapse = "-")
tt
# 1-2  3-4  5-6  7-8 9-10 
#  29   45   43   47   36
```

Comment: or maybe use `rollapply` again to also set the names: `names(tt) <- rollapply(names(table(a)), 2, by = 2, paste, collapse = "-")`

Comment: Nice one @G.Grothendieck

Comment: Your solution looks simple as well. Correct me if I'm wrong, but does the function `rollapply` work something like a sliding window? As far as I understand, rollapply moves the sliding window by the number specified in the `by` argument and then executes the specified function.

Comment: @MohideenImranKhan, exactly. Try and play around with it a bit by changing the arguments and you will see how it works. It's very easy

Answer (score 4):

Here is a faster option with `RcppRoll` and `tabulate`

```
library(RcppRoll)
nm1 <- do.call(paste, c(as.data.frame(matrix(1:10, ncol=2, byrow=TRUE)), list(sep="-")))
setNames(roll_sum(tabulate(a),2)[c(TRUE, FALSE)], nm1)
# 1-2  3-4  5-6  7-8 9-10 
#  29   45   43   47   36
```